# How to compile runtime-generated Angular8 code?

Tags: angular, angular8, dynamic-loading, angular-compiler

I'm creating Angular code at runtime, in particular, I use a SVG library in order to create a vector graphic that contains Angular code directives like `(click)='myMethod()'`, which, in turn, call methods I've statically defined in the SVG-enclosing component. Being generated at runtime I need to compile the created template and add it to a component. I implemented such code back then with Angular 3 with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/42065289#42065289) which was quite cumbersome. I tried to the copy the old code in an Angular 8 app:

```
private addComponent(template: string) {

    @Component({template: template + ' <div #target></div>'})
    class TemplateComponent {

      @ViewChild('target', {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef}) public target;

      constructor() {
      }

      public myMethod() {
        // do something     
      }
    }

    @NgModule({declarations: [TemplateComponent]})
    class TemplateModule {
      @ViewChild('target', {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef}) public target;
    }

    // ERROR in next line:
    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
        comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );
    this.container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

which now fails with

> ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
>       at Compiler._throwError (core.js:38932)

On the one hand, I have no clue why that error occurs. Everything I found on the internet was about [*critical* function syntax](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14763) in lazy module loading. On the other hand, I wonder, if five Angular major versions later, there is an other way to do it. I read about [Portals](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) but it seems to be about loading static templates dynamically, but not uncompiled templates generated on the fly. Looking forward to someone pointing me in the right direction.

**Post Scriptum:** Adding a Bounty for the one that can provide a basic running code snippet targetting Angular v9 in AoT mode. It has to contain a runtime-compiled template (e.g. from a string variable) containing a method call in the associated component.

Comment: You implemented that kind of code with **Angular 3**? :-)

Comment: The easy fix is to disable aot, but I doubt that this is a solution for you ?

Comment: @David, yes, very good hint. I should work in AoT. I added it to the post.

Comment: can you show your routing module ?

Comment: @nafeo module is loaded like this `{path: 'user', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule), data: {breadcrumb: 'User'}}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JIT compiler is now excluded by default from AOT bundles so you have to include it manually. You need to install the package `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` and add the `Compiler` providers to your application module. For example:

```
import { NgModule, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CompilerFactory, Compiler } from '@angular/core';
import { JitCompilerFactory } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true },
    { provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS] },
    { provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory] }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}
```

Then you have to also make some small changes to your code because you cannot set the template to be a variable using the `@Component` decorator it gives a compile error. The decorator must be run dynamically in code.

Here is your method updated with the changes:

```
private addComponent(template: string) {
  class TemplateComponent {

    @ViewChild('target', {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef}) public target;

    constructor() {
    }

    public myMethod() {
      // do something     
    }
  }

  class TemplateModule {
    @ViewChild('target', {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef}) public target;
  }

  const componentType = Component({template: template + '<div #target></div>'})(TemplateComponent)

  const componentModuleType = NgModule({declarations: [componentType]})(TemplateModule)

  const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(componentModuleType);
  const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
      comp.componentType === componentType
  );
  this.container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

I have created also a [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tcejuo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) where you can see it working.

For a more detailed sample on how to do this check this [Angular AOT Dynamic Components GitHub repository](https://github.com/CharlesElGriego/angular-aot-dynamic-components) with a full sample.

I found this in the [Angular GitHub issue about dynamically loading component templates](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15275). Since you use this it is probably good you follow the issue to be up to date on the developments.

Comment: You probably need to set `buildOptimizer : false` in `angular.json`, or it will not work when built in prod mode

Comment: @David, thanks for the hint. Will keep that in mind when we put the code in production.

Comment: Please also consider that dynamic module imports (e.g. `CommonModule`) would work only with `aot: false` in `angular.json`.